# Replace innerhtml with external page

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have a page that consists of a header div for navigation, a content div for content, and a footer div that just has some static information.

The idea is that when you click on something in the header bar, the content div changes its content accordingly. I'd like to store each content element in its own file, for ease of development. How can I go about filling in this `magicLoad` function I've written below?

I'm currently not using any framework (jquery comes to mind) but I'm certain not opposed to using one. If there's other best practices I'm violating here, I'm keen to know as well, but my primary goal is to load from an external page. How can I do this?

Here's a basic skeleton mockup of my setup right now. (There's more than just those 3 of course, but those are enough to get the point across.)

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function show(which) {
        document.getElementById(which).innerHtml = magicLoad(which + ".html");
        return false;
    }       
    function showHome() { show('home'); return false;} // for onload

    </script>
    <body>
    <div id="header">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show('home')">HOME</a> |
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show('training')">TRAINING</a> |
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show('audits')">AUDITS</a>
    </div>
    <div id="content">

    </div>
    <div id="footer">

    </div>
    </body>
    <script> window.onload=showHome; </script>
</html>
```

Comment: You're looking for Ajax.

Comment: @Truth no, ajax would be asynchronous. This is entirely synchronous. If I wanted someone else to control the content, then Ajax would be a great solution.

Comment: Ajax can very much be synchronous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the following, simple and straight

```
$('#which').load('test.html');
```

if which is coming as parameter

```
$('#'+which).load('test.html');
```

Comment: By the syntax I assume this is JQuery?

Comment: What if that HTML contains a full `<head>` to `<body>` tags? It doesn't make sense inside a div

Comment: you have to be careful with that, that's your responsibility with current specifications. it has to be `partial page`

Comment: So this was indeed very close to what I was looking for. Basically, `which` determined the html to load. So what I did was `$('#content_div').load(which + '.html');` but this guided me there. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to embed another webpage in one, you should think of using `<iframe>`.
Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show(which) {
    document.getElementById(which).src=which+".html";
    return false;
}       
function showHome() { show('home'); return false;} // for onload

</script>
<iframe id="home"></iframe>
```