# Using Jquery and AJAX to load html file into a div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

After being very helpfully pointed to AJAX and jquery as an answer to an earlier question, I found much helpful documentation, examples and questions. Particularly this...

[Replace innerhtml with external page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113119/replace-innerhtml-with-external-page)

But after banging my head against a brick wall for what seems like forever, I just can't get it to work! Hopefully it's something glaringly obvious to you guys! Again, thanks in advance!

Here's what I have...

```html
<head>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/new1.css" />
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(
    function navclick(which) {
     $('#container').load(which + '.html');
    }
   )
  </script>
  
</head>

<body id="main">

 <div>
 
  <a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="navclick('page1')">Page 1</a>
  <a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="navclick('page2')">Page 2</a>
 
 </div>
 
 <div id="container">
  <p>Placeholder text</p>
 </div>
 
 
</body>
```

Comment: Take your method out of the document ready and make it just a normal method and see if your onclicks start working.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply, unfortunately, that doesn't solve the problem. :(

Comment: Look at your network console and see if it is making the requests, and verify if they are being made that they are returning with a non-error response code

Comment: I am getting an error by the looks of it... Failed to load file:///E:/Dancefactors%20-%20new%20site/Test/function: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
send @ jquery.js:4
ajax @ jquery.js:4
r.fn.load @ jquery.js:4
navclick @ test.html:10
j @ jquery.js:2
k @ jquery.js:2
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery.js:2
i @ jquery.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.js:2
fire @ jquery.js:2
i @ jquery.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.js:2
ready @ jquery.js:2
S @ jquery.js:3

Comment: try to use only jQuery function call:  $(function () {  navclick = function (which) { $('#container').load(which + '.html'); } };

Comment: @CalvinNunes if his url that he is hitting isn't correct it doesn't matter if he uses only jQuery or not.

Comment: When I click one of the links it tells me... Uncaught ReferenceError: navclick is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Comment: The first error is telling you that you can't use ajax over `file:///`. Use a local webserver instead so you can serve over `http://`. And also do what Taplar said in the first comment - that will remove your Uncaught Reference error. There's no need to define a function within document.ready, since it won't be executed until it's called anyway. document.ready is only to stop code which would normally be executed immediately it was loaded, from executing until the DOM is fully complete.

Comment: Running the site on a local host fixed everything perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do it:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.nav').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("name") + '.html';
    $("#container").load(url);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/new1.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <a href="#" name="page1" class="nav">Page 1</a>
  <a href="#" name="page2" class="nav">Page 2</a>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <p>Placeholder text</p>
</div>
```